# Is it possible to use QQmlApplicationEngine on a QWidget-based application?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qml

I have a software that is completely coded in python using PyQt5 with QWidget classes.
I recently came across QML and found that the visual results seemed much better than in QWidget.

I wonder if there is a way to use the QMLEngine on the .ui generated from QtDesginer and apply QML styles on the .ui?

I found this [repository](https://github.com/seanwu1105/pyqt5-qtquick2-example) which gives results similar to what I hoped to achieve.

Comment: You can use [QQuickWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html#details) to embed `QML` into `QWidget` application. In any case this is not the best way to work with 
 `QtQuick`.

Comment: As an alternative you might want to look at using a [style sheet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html) with your `QWidget` based app.  It can make a huge difference to the appearance.

Comment: Yes, I'm using StyleSheets, but the results are nowhere near what I can achieve with QML.

Comment: @PyThagoras If you want the QML styles to be applied to the Qt Widgets then that is not possible, if you want the QML styles then you will have to rewrite your application with QML items.

Comment: Thank you, that was my question. I thought it might be possible to do this without rewriting the application.